# Saving strings from the input .txt filename - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Via textscan, I am reading a number of .txt files:

fid1 = fopen('Ev_An_OM2_l5_5000.txt','r');

This is a simplification as in reality I am loading several hundred .txt files via:

```
files = dir('Ev_An*.txt');
```

Important information not present within the .txt files themselves are instead part of the filename.

Is there a way to concisely extract portions of the filename and save them as strings/numbers? For example saving 'OM2' and '5000' from the above filename as variables.

`fileparts` appears to require the full path of the file rather than just defaulting to the MATLAB folder as with `textscan`.

Comment: How do you construct the filename in the first place, to be used in `fopen`? Why do you need to reverse-engineer?

Comment: Added an edit to explain this.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. How can you tell `matlab` to open `'Ev_An_OM2_l5_5000.txt'` and not something else? How do you construct this filename? Do you have a database with the filenames?

Comment: This is a simplified example for the purposes of the question - I am otherwise using `files = dir('Ev_An*.txt');` to batch load hundreds of .txt files with similar filenames from the default MATLAB directory.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was interested in. See my answer below whether it's suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how fixed your filename is. If your filename is in the string `filename`, then you can use `regexp` to extract parts of your filename, like so:

```
filename = 'Ev_An_OM2_l5_5000.txt'; %or whatever
parts = regexp(filename,'[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+_([^\.]+)\.txt','tokens');
```

This will give you `parts{1}=='OM2'` and `parts{2}=='5000'`, assuming that your `filename` is always in the form of

```
something_something_somethingofinterest_something_somethingofinterest.txt
```

**Update:**
If you like structs more than cells, then you can name your tokens like so:

```
parts = regexp(filename,'[^_]+_[^_]+_(?<first>[^_]+)_[^_]+_(?<second>[^\.]+)\.txt','names');
```

in which case `parts.first=='OM2'` and `parts.second=='5000'`. You can obviously name your tokens according to their actual meaning, since they are important. You just have to change `first` and `second` accordingly in the code above.

**Update2:**
If you use `dir` to get your filenames, you should have a struct array with loads of unnecessary information. If you really just need the file names, I'd use a for loop like so:

```
files = dir('Ev_An*.txt');
for i=1:length(files)
   filename=files(i).name;
   parts = regexp(filename,'[^_]+_[^_]+_(?<first>[^_]+)_[^_]+_(?<second>[^\.]+)\.txt','tokens');

   %here do what you want with parts.first, parts.second and the file itself
end
```

Comment: What would be the best way to extract the filename into a variable to begin with?